# Quotient group of $C^*$ by Circle group is isomorphic to $R^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

$C^*$ is the set of complex numbers except $0$ and $S'$ is the circle group. I have to show the quotient group $C^*/S'$ is isomorphic to $R^+$.
Let's define $f:C^*→ R^+$, $z→|z|$. Why is $Kerf$ $S'$? If I show that, the map is clearly surjective and by the first isomorphism theorem, $C^*/S'$ would be isomorphic to $R^+$.
Is my reasoning right? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb R^+$ under multiplication, right? Anyway, $x \in \ker f$ if and only if $|z| = 1$ if and only if  $z$ lies on the unit circle.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\ker f=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^*\,|\,\lvert z\rvert=1\}=S^1$.